# sending an object to thread back and forth

Tags: java, client-server, serversocket

I'm trying to make a simple server client thread application in Java, about a quiz-like game.
I have a `Main` class as its "brain", which will handle the main processes like asking the questions, checking the answers, etc. I have two other classes, `ServerHandler` and `Player`. `ServerHandler` is to connect `Main` with `Player`. So far, the problem is that I want to send properties of `Main` to `ServerThread`. I tried using `this` but it doesn't work. Any suggestions to help improve my program would also be welcome.

```
    public class Main 
    {
        public static int MYECHOPORT = 8189;
        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            // TODO code application logic here

            ServerSocket s = null;
            int count;
            count=0;
            Pemain [] player=new Pemain[3];

        try 
            {
            s = new ServerSocket(MYECHOPORT);
        } 
            catch(IOException e) 
            {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        while (true) 
            {
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                {
                    player[i]=new Pemain();
                    player[i].setNo(i+1);
                    count++;
                }            
            try 
                {
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                    {
                        player[i].setS(s.accept());
                    }
            } 
                catch(IOException e) 
                {
            System.out.println(e);
            continue;
            }

                if(count==3)
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                    {
                        new ServerHandler(player[i].getS(), this).start();
                    }
                }


                // ignore
            }
        }  

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*this* won't work because you are in a static method (main()). Refactor to a non-static method.

Strip static fom main and rename to m(String[] args). Then insert this main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   new Main().m(args)
}
```

Comment: new Main().m(args) can be called at any method from Main? not just main?

Comment: `new Main().m(null)` may be called anywhere in your code. But if you don't get it, you should read more Java tutorials ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to avoid saying "it doesn't work". Tell *how* it doesn't work. Tell what happens. Tell the error message you get.

Second, you seem to have not grasped basic OO concepts such as objects and static methods, and dealing with *very* complex stuff such as socket IO and multiple threads is too early.

Now to your problem: you're trying to pass `this` as a method argument. `this` represents the object on which the current method is called. But the method where you're trying to do that is a static method, so it doesn't have any enclosing object. The code of the main method should probably look like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.execute();
}
```

Where the `execute()` method contains what your main method currently contains.

Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html for more information about static class members.

Comment: it got error as nonstatic variables... i assume main can be sent anywhere after execute? like declare it as private data member and call execute before main get sent to another method?yes, im not used to static variables... i usually used private only and only try nonstatic variables...

Comment: As I said, read  about basic OO concepts. Follow the link I gave you and read the whole tutorial. Buy and read an introductory Java book. And starts with easier stuff. Multi-threading is very complex. I have more than 14 years of experience with Java and I still find it hard.